# Increment of +1 for int variable

Tags: asp.net, for-loop, increment

I am trying to make an int variable automatically increase itself by 1 each time I click on an aspx button.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int UserID = 0;
      for(int i =0; i<9999; i ++) {
         userID++;
       }

     lbNumber.Text = UserID.toString();
}
```

It always comes out as 9999. I would like it to be 1 on the first click, 2 on the second click, etc.
Sorry for asking such a simple question, but I do not know how or what to search on this forum to get the right answer.

Comment: Just as a side note, your code is doing exactly what you told it to.  It is looping from 0 to 9999, and then returning 9999.  You should do some basic programming tutorials.  They would be beneficial.

Comment: You are incrementing a variable named `userID`. In most languages this is different than `UserID`. Not sure about ASP.NET, though.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop will iterate until it reaches 9999 each time. It needs to be replaced with the `if` statement so that it stops at 9999.

You need to restore the previous value of the number:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userID = Convert.ToInt32(lbNumber.Text);
    if (userID < 9999)
    {
        userID++;
    }

    lbNumber.Text = userID.ToString();
}
```

Also, case matters in C# for variable names. Be sure to always use the same case, as seen in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript or jQuery to achive this.

Below is the solution for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
 <div id="likes">
<span class="figure"></span>
</div>
<button type="button" id="like" >Like</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0; $("#like").click(function(){ clicks++; $('.figure').html(clicks);});
</script>
```